# Running metasploit on android error

Tags: linux, termux

I am trying to run metasploit on Android using Termux.
I've already installed it but when i try to run msfconsole command i get this error:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- /data/data/com.termux/files/home/metasploit-framework/msfconsole (LoadError)
```

Thanks for response

EDIT :

[image: IMG:]

Second EDIT

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Please Share a Screenshot of the Home Directory on your Termux Terminal....to do so... Simply Execute the following commands and Share the Screenshot of the result... cd ~ && ls

Comment: You should try to execute metasploit and then make the screenshot. How did you install metaspoit?

Comment: I installed it from this tutorial : https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/forum/to-install-metasploit-framework-android-part-1-termux-0186792/            Second screenshot added

Comment: If you're new to MetaSploit Framework, I **strongly** recomment *against* trying to run it on Android. MSF itself is meant for experts, and configuring it on non-GNU/Linux systems add another layer of complexity as well as requirement for previous knowledge in related subjects.

Comment: Also, the tutorial provided many ways of installation. Which one exactly did you follow?

Comment: I followed the first way.